# Connecting local MySQL database inside a Docker container?

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, docker-for-windows

Here is how I am trying to connect. But it shows:

> Host 'host.docker.internal' is not allowed to connect

YAML:

```
 environment:
       - MYSQL_DSN=mysql:host=192.168.0.1;port=3307;dbname=dbname
```

Comment: Are you looking to connect from a container to the host database, or a container to a container database?

Comment: @halfer container to the host database!

Comment: OK. I am confused though - your connection string in a Docker Compose env var is `192.168.0.1`, but MySQL has seen `host.docker.internal` - are you sure the connection string `MYSQL_DSN` is being used?

Comment: It's worth noting that the container cannot "see" IP addresses that your host does - `192.168.0.1` is probably your LAN router IP, but that's on a different network.

Comment: (Or it could be your host computer on your LAN, but the same observation applies - the Docker virtual networking device can't see that).

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` this solved the problem

Comment: OK. Note that your env var is not being used, at least for this connection - maybe try removing it and see if it breaks anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL user does not allow external connections.

Update your user to allow external connections using "GRANT" or create a new user using "CREATE USER": https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/

To accept all connections, use `%` wildcard as a host part.

Answer (score -1):

1. create mysql data as a container: named: mysql-data
2. create docker container for mysql server to use mysql DB created in step 1. this is your inside docker conatiner
3. mysql client should be there on the host machine

for above 2 steps use yaml file as:

```
services:
  mysql-data:
    image: image_path/mysql-data:latest
    container_name: mysql-data

  my-container-name:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.6
    container_name: my-container-name
    env_file:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MYSQL_USER=username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 9999:3306
    volumes_from:
      - mysql-data
```

login to mysql DB using command:

```
mysql -h <your-host-ip> -P9999 -uusername -ppassword
```